# Minecraft Launcher: no lwjgl in java.library.path

Tags: c++, qt, jar, minecraft

I'm trying to launch minecraft from my Qt program using this code:

```
params.append("java -Xmx1024M ");
params.append("-Djava.library.path=" + QDir::toNativeSeparators("C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl-platform/2.9.1/") + " ");
params.append("-cp C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/java3d/vecmath/1.3.1/vecmath-1.3.1.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/net/sf/trove4j/trove4j/3.0.3/trove4j-3.0.3.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/ibm/icu/icu4j-core-mojang/51.2/icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.5/jopt-simple-4.5.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/paulscode/codecjorbis/20101023/codecjorbis-20101023.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/paulscode/codecwav/20101023/codecwav-20101023.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/paulscode/libraryjavasound/20101123/libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/paulscode/librarylwjglopenal/20100824/librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/paulscode/soundsystem/20120107/soundsystem-20120107.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.10.Final/netty-all-4.0.10.Final.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/google/guava/guava/15.0/guava-15.0.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/net/java/jinput/jinput/2.0.5/jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/net/java/jutils/jutils/1.0.0/jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/com/mojang/authlib/1.2/authlib-1.2.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.0-beta9/log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.0-beta9/log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.1-nightly-20131120/lwjgl-2.9.1-nightly-20131120.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl_util/2.9.1-nightly-20131120/lwjgl_util-2.9.1-nightly-20131120.jar;C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/libraries/tv/twitch/twitch/5.12/twitch-5.12.jar;");
params.append(QDir::toNativeSeparators("C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/versions/1.7.4/1.7.4.jar") + " ");
params.append("net.minecraft.client.main.Main ");
params.append("--username " + sUsername + " ");
params.append("--version 1.7.4 ");
params.append("--assetIndex 1.7.4 ");
params.append("--assetsDir " + QDir::toNativeSeparators("C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/assets") + " ");
params.append("--userProperties {} ");
params.append("--gameDir C:/Users/sercinci/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft ");
params.append("--accessToken " + sLogID + "");
```

The response is: `No such file or directory`.

Using the same code (same found on the internet and on stack overflow too) directly in cmd :

```
java -Xmx1024M
-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.1-nightly-20131120\
-cp C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\java3d\vecmath\1.3.1\vecmath-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\trove4j\trove4j\3.0.3\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.10.Final\netty-all-4.0.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\15.0\guava-15.0.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.2\authlib-1.2.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.1-nightly-20131120\lwjgl-2.9.1-nightly-20131120.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.1-nightly-20131120\lwjgl_util-2.9.1-nightly-20131120.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch\5.12\twitch-5.12.jar;C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.4\1.7.4.jar net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username federico_ercole91@yahoo.it
--version 1.7.4 --assetIndex 1.7.4 --assetsDir C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets --userProperties {} --gameDir C:\Users\sercinci\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft
--accessToken 2cbfa7d1c1764c2b9ec0f9685ef849f5
```

It says:

> no lwjgl in java.library.path

I've tried with `%appdata%` path, with 1.7.4 and 1.7.10 versions and checked all the paths and libraries versions. I've already checked all the others related questions but they didn't solve my problem.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Try specifying the full path to java

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the correct version of the libraries. The default minecraft launcher updates the libraries from the minecraft website, so the code you used may not be up to date. To get the proper libraries, do this.

- Open the default launcher
- Make a new profile
- Change the Java executable to something that will print out all arguments, like a `.bat` file with this in it

```
@echo off
echo %*
pause
```

- The "Game Output" tab should show all of the arguments used to run Java

You can then go through that and find all of the libraries. I'd recommend using your own directory (not `.minecraft`) and downloading the libraries with your own launcher, so you won't have to recheck the libraries all the time.

[This](http://wiki.vg/Game_files) is Mojang's API page for downloading the assets and libraries, so it could be helpful.